# Merge every to 2 row in loop to one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have around 20 objects like this one below,

```
{ 
       isReadOnly: false
       isRequired: false
       isResettable: false
       name: "test1"
},
{ 
       isReadOnly: false
       isRequired: false
       isResettable: false
       name: "test2"
}
```

I need to merge them into new 10 object, where

0, 1 -> 0 {0: data0, 1: data1}

2, 3 -> 1 {0: data2, 1: data3}

4, 5 -> 2 {0: data4, 1: data5}

x
x

18, 19 -> 9 {0, data18, 1: data19}

20 -> {0: data20, 1: null (or do not exist)}

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you'd like the output object(s) to look like, can you elaborate?

Comment: What is a '10 object'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [...Array(20).keys()].map((_, index) => ({ 
       isReadOnly: false,
       isRequired: false,
       isResettable: false,
       name: index
}));

let combinedArr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2){
    combinedArr.push({0: arr[i], 1: arr[i + 1]})
}

console.log(combinedArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, its solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have array of objects like [{data0}, {data1}, {data3},...,{data19}]
and you want to make array with 10 object then you can acieve this like:

```
let oldArr = [{data0}, {data1}, {data3},...,{data19}]
let newArr = []
for (let i=0; i < oldArr.length; i=i+2) {
  let obj = {0: oldArr[i], 1: oldArr[i+1]}
  newArr.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the proposed solution works as the previous ones, but there is a small difference. Let's say the `mainData` contains 21 objects, the last index `i` would be **20**, as we tend to access `mainData[21]` it would rise an error since the index 21 does not exist. Hence, I always check whether the next object is the last one or not.

```
const mainData = [...yourObjects];

let mergedArray = [];

const size = mainData.length;

for (let i=0; i < size; i+2) {
   mergedArray.push({
      0: mainData[index],
      1: (index + 2 <= size) ? mainData[index+1]: null
   });

}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with an explanation of your code and how it solves the question? Code alone isn't always too helpful in helping people understand where they're going wrong.

Comment: I've updated my solution. Basically, `index+2 <= size` will check whether the last even index exists or not to prevent accessing to an undefined object.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.